# How to skip Vagrant triggers from command line

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

In our vagrant file we've couple of triggers.By default I would like to run all triggers which is working fine. is there any way to skip the Vagrant triggers from command line?

**Vagrantfile**

```
config.trigger.before [:provision] do
      puts "> Running gradle "
      gradlew 'quickCompile'
    end

    config.trigger.after [:provision] do
      puts "> Running gradle to check database"
      gradlew 'checkDB'
    end
```

vagrant v1.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you can - refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers#skipping-execution)

> Triggers won't run if `VAGRANT_NO_TRIGGERS` environment variable is set.

so you can just set the variable to `true` and your triggers will be skipped

As part of the migration to the trigger plugin to vagrant core, the env variable is not available anymore

Comment: btw. this env var doesn't exist https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/other/environmental-variables

Comment: right, does not exist anymore since triggers has been implemented as part of the core vagrant but was part of the trigger plugin back then.